# Setting asp:label text colour based on text

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, data-binding

I am databinding a gridview and one of the columns is defined as shown below. What I would like to do is to colour the text depending on whether the text says "Yes" or "No". If the text is "Yes" I'd like to set it to red else set it to green. Can this be done and if so should it be done via css or can I add some code to the line?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Validated" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Product">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblValidated" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Validation") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should do what you want.

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Validated" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Product">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblValidated" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Validation") %>' CssClass='<%# SetColor(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Validation")) %>'  />
</ItemTemplate>
```

**C#**

```
public string SetColor(string Text)
{
    return Text.ToUpper == "YES" ? "GreenClass" : "RedClass"
}
```

**CSS**

```
.GreenClass{color:green;}
.RedClass{color:red;}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be a <%#SetColor instead of <%=SetColor ?

Comment: Gives the error "The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context" :(

Comment: Don't you have to make that with css class? In order to keep the separation between content and style. After that if the color of the YES will change, a modification in the CSS will be enough